# Running an exe at System Startup

Tags: .net, windows, exe, startup

I have an exe that I need to run at system startup. The exe has some dependency on config file & other dll's. The solution I tried is by copying the exe in System StartUp folder. Along with the exe, I also had to copy the other config & dll files. The issue I am facing is that at system startup, the OS tries to open other files as well. For e.g. config file is getting opened in Visual Studio.

Is there any other approach of running an exe with dependencies at system startup?

Comment: leave your files in their normal place, put a **shortcut** to your program in your startup folder. If you put anything else in the startup folder the system will try to run it at startup using the associated program.

Comment: http://superuser.com is a good site for such questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by *Mark Hall*, you should put only shortcuts into the startup folder. In fact, the whole start menu is meant to contain nothing but shortcuts only, while the actual programs live everywhere else, typically program files, together with all the files they need.
Putting the whole thing in the start menu will only clutter it to the user.